# MVC3 razor get Browser Screen Width and Height in View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor

In my website I am generating a Bitmap dynamically and it needs to be rendered according to the browsers width and height so there is no overflow on the page.

I have successfully created an image and rendered it but I do not know how to get the browsers width and height and pass it to the action for the image render

View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Home</h2>
<br />
<img src="@Url.Action("Image", new { height = , width = })" alt="image" usemap="#clickMap" height="" width="" />
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Image(int width, int height)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    var image = DynamicImages.ImageGeneration.GetWorkflow(width, height);

    image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

    return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
}
```

I have put a jQuery function in a file called Browser.js in to get the screen height but I dont have a clue how to reference this:

```
function getWidth() {
    return $(window).width();
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: you understand that a user can resize his browser .. right ? (*and then those hardcoded values will be invalid..*). Better to use CSS to resize the image..

Comment: If you user resizes the browser the image will have to be rendered, which I can do on an ajaz call. Using CSS will not work due to mappings that will also be created at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get this working.
Rather than adding an image element to the page and changing the source I have simply generated an image tag in a function and added that to a div in the page. as for the call to the action I hard coded the url call (which is what @Url.Action() does anyway) and this works
Here is my code:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Home</h2>
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        renderWorkflow();
    });

    function renderWorkflow() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        var height = $(window).height();
        var imageLink = "<img id=\"workflow\" src=\"/Home/WorkflowImage?width=" + width + "&height=" + height + "\" alt=\"Workflow Image\" />";

        $("#workflowImage").html(imageLink);
    }

</script>
<div id="workflowImage">
    <p>Java script must be enabled in order to render the workflow</p>
</div>
<map id="clickMap" name="clickMap">
</map>
```

Comment: All the help above was usefull and steered me in the right direction. I just could not get the examples provided in the answers above working

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like the following:

```
$("img-selector").attr("src", "@Url.Action("Image")" + "?height=" + getHeight() 
    + "&width=" + getWidth());
```

Comment: The call to the Action needs to pass 2 paramters as shown i the question action Method Image(int width , int height)

Answer (score 0):

you can do a ajax request to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Height = //get height
  var Width = // get width

 $.get('@Url.Action("Image", "Controller")', { width: width, height: Height}, function (data) {              

        });
</script>
```